# Qual a melhor alternativa: defines, enums ou variáveis?

Tags: c++

Recentemente, em um projeto onde tenho que declarar muitas contantes, me veio essa dúvida. Qual a melhor opção `define's`, `enum's` ou variáveis constantes?

A princípio penso que usar `enum` seja a melhor alternativa por não poluir o código e funcionar melhor com o auto-completador do IDE, mas quais seriam os **prós** e **contras** de cada abordagem?

Exemplo das opções que tenho:

```
enum Pin
{
    PIN_00 = 0x10,
    PIN_01 = 0x11,
    PIN_02 = 0x12,
    // ... muitos outros 
};
```

Ou:

```
#define PIN_00 0x10
#define PIN_01 0x11
#define PIN_02 0x12
// ... outros defines
```

Ou:

```
namespace Pin
{
     const int PIN_00 = 0x10;
     const int PIN_01 = 0x11;
     const int PIN_02 = 0x12;
     // ... Outros declarações
}
```

Comment: Melhor ou pior em absoluto não existem. Quais são os prós e contras de cada abordagem, no entanto, é algo que pode ser respondido.

Comment: Eu prefiro evitar define e enum pois nem sempre os compiladores conseguem tratar este tipo de informação na hora de mostrar os valores durante uma execução em debug mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se todas as contantes estão relacionadas e você quer dar coesão a elas na forma de um tipo, `enum` é a melhor escolha, pois não permitem que por engano você atribua uma valor errado a elas.

```
Pin pin1 = PIN_00; //Ok
Pin pin2 = 0x10;   //Não compila
```

Agora se o propósito é apenas dar nome a um [número mágico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29), existe controvérsia. Pessoalmente eu prefiro `const` do que `#define`, porque as variáveis `const` são tratadas pelo compilador mesmo. Você tem um identificador, com tipo e valor bem definidos. Já o `define` é tratado pelo pré-processador, podendo gerar resultados inesperados em alguns casos. Por exemplo:

```
const int CONST = 2 + 5;
#define DEFINE 2 + 5

int x = 3 * CONST;  //Resultado = 3 * (2 + 5)
int y = 3 * DEFINE; //Resultado = 3 * 2 + 5 !!!
```

Outro problema é que o tipo do `define` é apenas definido pelo literal, o que também pode gerar problemas:

```
#define FATOR 1.5

double val = FATOR / 2;
```

Se algum dia alguém mudar o valor de `FATOR` para `1` (em vez de `1.0`) aquela divisão vira uma divisão inteira, cujo resultado é `0`, em vez do `0.5` esperado. Este problema não acontece se `FATOR` for `const double`.

Answer (score 2):

Existem diversos prós e contras de cada abordagem dependendo do contexto, com relação ao consumo de memória e desempenho acredito que o enum e a variável constante sejam iguais já que o enum é como uma variável mais fortemente tipada. Já o define não ocupa memória já que ele é avaliado pelo pré processador que substitui o trecho em que ele aparece pela sua definição.

Comment: O impacto de memória e de desempenho é zero para todas as alternativas. No caso da variável, ela ocupará espaço na memória somente se você tentar criar um ponteiro para ela (nos outros casos isso não é possível).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal No caso da variável, se eu utilizar essa abordagem, o compilador tratará a variável como um literal? Ou ele armazenará a variável na memória? Não entendi muito bem isso.

Comment: @Lucas se for uma variavel global você deve  a fazer `static const`. Sendo local só o `const` basta. Nesse caso e se você nunca criar um ponteiro para a variável, a otimização é trivial e qualquer compilador vai aplicar "inline" na variável.